# Ubuntu 20.04 on vm crashes on log-in screen

Tags: 20.04, vmware

My Ubuntu had internet access problems. I tried rebooting, and for some reason it didn't reboot properly. After reading some data from some post online on how to fix booting problem I decided to use safe mode reboot.
It didn't go well either.
Next i tried to use the recovery mode dpkg, it deleted some packages, installed some and after that it got even worse. Now I can see my log-in screen but sometimes it crashes before I can even enter the password. Sometimes after I can't use my Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

1. help me fix my VM so it will open (already tried disable 3D acceleration / changing graphic controller)
2. help me get my information from the broken vm/vdi
   if it helps here you can access my vm/ubuntu logs https://ufile.io/f/aluhf
   thanks for helpers..

Comment: Hello. The following statement taken from your question are not making any sense. <After reading some data from some post > and <I used the recovery mode dpkg, deleted some packages, installed some>. What data from where and what did you do? What did you delete and what did you install. As written there is no way to help you. Sorry.

Comment: I didn't do anything on my own, just tried to normally reboot before this all mess staterted, about installing and deleting: I'm not really sure because that was dpkg did it himself so i guess he found broken packages and deleted them and tried to installed them from new.. maybe the logs i uploaded will help you know? 
if that's not enough information please tell me what to add

Comment: Who is this mysterious himself person you keep referring to?

Comment: The ubuntu 20.04 recovery mode dpkg option.

Comment: `dpkg` not a person so it should be "itself". Now, re: your problem (1) Any VM should have snapshots you can use to get back to a working state as well as backups of any data you can't afford to loose like in any other installed OS. (2) Not having those is a now a huge problem and vague descriptions like "it deleted some packages, installed some" as well as the previously commented ones are useless to provide a solution. (3) In any case "internet access problems" AREN'T solved by any of the things your description *suggests* you did.

Comment: Sorry for my English.
About the deleting and installing, i attached some logs on the post, if there is something else i can add please let me know.
about your tips:
1) how do i perform such a thing in my current situation?
3) i didn't did it to fix my internet, to fix the internet i only tried to reboot, the problem started by itself after that.